# File chooser returning wrong Uri from recents, any way to get the right one?

Tags: android, uri

When I open a file from "Recents" I get this format Uri:

`content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1000000040`

instead of this:

`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADCIM%2Fx%2F24538c.png`

and I need that one.

I tried converting it to a File and back.

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to a File? You can just use the `Uri` returned.

Comment: @Andrew it doesn't work, I get a FileNotFoundException, from the library I'm using.